# azure : http image access to a blob storage with firewall enable

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I will try to keep this simple.

**1)** I have a VM : NGINX server serving a webpage. ( **azure VM** )
**2)** I have a storage with a Blob folder called web-images. ( **azure storage** )

This storage are fully block to only " Selected networks "

**Question:**
How does a page in the NGINX server can point to the blob storage and get the file?

**Example:**

```
<img src="https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/web-images/demoImage-1.jpg" >
```

thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that you can't. Because the storage account is restricted to selected networks and when a user accesses a resource in that account through a browser they are accessing it via their network and thus they will not be able to access the file.

One option is to download the file on your server from the storage account and then use a link of your servers in your HTML pages but then it defeats the process of having files in storage in the first place.